# iPhone/iPad App updates within App itself

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I know that after I have deployed my ipad/iphone app into App Store, it will notify those who have installed my app when I have a new update.

However, I have seen some apps getting an update prompt after opening the app itself. It will actually do the updates within the app itself, instead of from the App Store. Would like to know how this is being done. Is it through application coding?

My app displays information of certain projects based on categories. Would like to know if the user can actually choose the categories he/she wishes to update, if the update is done via the app itself, as described above.

Please advise. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update the actual application code, but you can update content if you have a webservice set up that the app can check-in with.

Conceptually it is no different then the Facebook app which updates its content (your news feed) when you open the app.

There are many ways to do this type of thing and a quick Google search should lead you to some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am wondering how I can just update the contents instead of replacing the whole application as I just need to change some images or xml files. Please take a look at this link as the new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990926/xcode-images-and-xml-deployment Thanks.