# XCode - Images and XML Deployment

Tags: xml, xcode, image, deployment

My company is currently writing an iOS app whereby we will display some of the projects which we have done. I understand that all the Images and XML files will be compiled into the App Package file.

Would like to know if it is possible to call a web service and update the image and XML files whenever we have updates to our projects. Are we able to access the app package contents directly when we want to do update instead of recompiling everything? This is because we don't think we should compile the whole application when we just want to change one of the images, for example.

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question about accessing the package contents is no, but that is OK because you can work around it.

The way I would this when the app is launched for the first time on a device I would copy the images and xml files to the Documents folder. Then whenever you open the app you can check to see if the assets in the Documents folder need updating, and if they do, then you can download the assets from the server into your Documents folder.